# File ended while scanning use of \alignat, can't find the problem

Tags: math-mode, errors, amsmath, alignat

I have this set of aligned equations and I'm trying to find out why it's giving me my error; as far as I can tell, I don't have any missing brackets or anything. My I'll only post the heading and block causing my problem, but I do have another block of alignat that was able to compile properly before adding this one

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Homework 3 my name}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
%
\#2
%
\begin{alignat}{1}
& \lambda = 1.49x10^{16}\frac{kg}{km^{2}s}\mu = 1.61x10^{16}\frac{kg}{km^{2}s}\\
& \rho = 2.75x10^{12}\frac{kg}{km^{3}}\\
& \alpha = \sqrt{\frac{(1.49x10^{16}+2*1.61x10^{16}}{2.75x10^{12}}\\
& \alpha = 131\frac{km}{s}\\
& \Beta = \sqrt{\frac{\mu}{\rho}}\\
& \Beta = \sqrt{\frac{1.61x10^{16}}{2.75x10^{12}}}\\
& \Beta = 75.5\frac{km}{s}
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

The #2 is just because this is problem 2 and I've cut out problem 1 for brevity

Comment: I think what you want is `align` environment.

Comment: Also, `\Beta` is not default. Maybe use `\beta` instead.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The third line, beginning with `\alpha`, looks suspicious.  There's an unmatched opening parenthesis, and I think there's not a closing brace for the `\sqrt`.  (Not tested, just eyeballed.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton, you are right.

Comment: Not related to the problem: I suggest using `\times` rather than `x` for a multiplication symbol.

Comment: Also, load the `siunitx` package and then `\si{\kilogram}`, for example, and others.

Comment: @Sigur: Unless it is a capital β? :–)

Comment: @Bernard, but from some package, right?

Comment: @Sigur: Needless – a capital β  is a simple `Β`.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Sigur, here is a code with a simplified typing, which uses the \SI command from `siunitx` to ensure correct formatting and spacing of units. An unrelated remark: there's no difference between `alignat{1}`and a simple `align`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Homework 3 my name}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
%
\#2

\sisetup{per-mode=fraction, detect-display-math}
\begin{alignat}{1}
& \lambda =\SI{1.49 e16 }{\kg\per\km\squared\per\s}\qquad\mu = \SI{1.61 e 16} {\kg\per\km\squared\per\s}\\
& \rho = \SI{2.75 e12 }{\kg\per\km\cubed}\\
& \alpha = \sqrt{\frac{\num{1.49 e16} +2\cdot\num{1.61 e16}}{\num{2.75 e12}}}\\
& \alpha = \SI{131}{\km\per\s}\\
& \beta = \sqrt{\frac{\mu}{\rho}}\\
& \beta = \sqrt{\frac{\num{1.61 e16}}{\num{2.75 e12}}} \\
& \beta = \SI{75.5}{\km\per\s}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Each unit with a `\per` before goes to the denominator. If you remove the \per before \s, it goes to the numerator. No idea why.

Comment: `\kg\per\km\squared\s` would be ambiguous. Each unit that has to go to the denominator should be preceded by `\per`.

Comment: @egreg: I also  noticed that grouping the units of the denominator with a pair of braces to disambiguate, the fraction per-mode was lost.